# PySpark fails to select column after pivot

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with a Timestamp column, a Tag column and a Value column.
I did a pivot like this:

```
df = df.groupBy("Timestamp").pivot("Tag").mean()
```

Which works well, gives me what I want. When I show columns, I get

```
df.columns
----------------------------------------
['Timestamp', 'TAG:Tag1.val', 'TAG:Tag2.val', 'TAG:Tag3.val']
```

But then when I try to select a column, I have this error:

```
df.select('TAG:Tag1.val')
----------------------------------------
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`TAG:Tag1.val`&#39; given input columns: [Timestamp, TAG:Tag1.val, TAG:Tag2.val, TAG:Tag3.val];;
```

I tried by giving the name directly, by using `df.columns[0], df.schema.fieldNames()`, by doing `df=df.toDF(*df.schema.fieldNames())` before select.

Always the same error message. Do you know why is it doing so?

I also tried to hardcode the column's list in `.pivot("Tag", list_tags)`, got the same result.

I also need to tell you that selecting Timestamp works perfectly well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please  take a moment to check tips on how to ask  : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can try : df1.columns = [f'{x}_' for x in df.columns] ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by replacing all ':' in the tags by '_'.
For a reason I don't know, pyspark did not read correctly ':'

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way, you need to wrap the column names with backticks:

```
df.select('`TAG:Tag1.val`').show()
```

To check all columns, you can do:

```
df.select([f'`{x}`' for x in df.columns]).show()
```